# Changing precedence in a Spring repository method

Tags: java, spring

Having a method like:

```
Collection<MyEntity> findByXAndYOrZ(Object x, Object y, Object z);
```

it seems to return cases where MyEntity has **X AND Y**  plus cases where MyEntity has **Z** so like:

> findBy(XAndY)Or(Z).

Is it possible by method naming to have it filter like:

> findBy(X)And(YOrZ).

so that it would return cases **X AND Y** plus cases **X AND Z**?

I am just about to code this as a **specification** but wondering if there is a clean way out with correct method naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there is a way to specify it as findByXAndYOrXAndZ, won't it lead to a method that reduces code readability? In such scenarios, I would resort to using @Query with a sql statement that can be executed and keep the method name simple.

Answer (score 1):

The dox only confirm what you have observed.
There is no mention of a way to change the default precedence of `And` and `Or` operators.

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)